# Select multiple columns with only one distinct column in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to query an `SQL` database to find all distinct values of one column and I need an arbitrary value from another two columns. For example, consider the following table with three columns: `CurrencyCode`, `BuyRate` and `SellRate`:

```
CurrencyCode  BuyRate  SellRate
AUD           1.037    1.97
AUD           1.079    1.99
EUR           0.7288   0.8763
EUR           0.731    0.88
GBP           0.59     0.72
```

I wish to retrieve one row with distinct `CurrencyCode`, perhaps getting these three rows:

```
CurrencyCode  BuyRate  SellRate
AUD           1.037    1.97
EUR           0.7288   0.8763
GBP           0.59     0.72
```

I tried my `SQL` query like:

```
SELECT distinct CurrencyCode, BuyRate, SellRate FROM  Currencies
```

But I am not getting the desired result as it districts all the columns.

Comment: Which dbms product are you using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try with `GROUP BY` clause and `MIN` function as below

```
SELECT CurrencyCode, MIN(BuyRate), MIN(SellRate)
FROM  Currencies
GROUP BY CurrencyCode
```

Answer (score 2):

Till now I found this is the best answer to get `Min(SellRate)` on the basis of `Min(BuyRate)`

eg.

```
    CurrencyCode    BuyRate   SellRate
       AUD           1.037     1.97
       AUD           1.079     1.89  //Changed from 1.99 to 1.89
       AUD           1.038     1.77  //New row added
       EUR           0.7288    0.8763
       EUR           0.731     0.88
       GBP           0.59      0.72
```

Here I am expecting `AUD`rows for `BuyRate` and `SaleRate` will be `1.037` and `1.97`

```
select CurrencyCode, Min(BuyRate) as BuyRate, 
(select top 1 SellRate from Currencies as C 
where C.CurrencyCode=Currencies.CurrencyCode 
and 
C.BuyRate= Min(Currencies.BuyRate) order by SellRate) as SellRate
from Currencies 
group
by CurrencyCode
```